# Running a task every hour, on an iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, cocoa-touch

I have a bunch (1500+) of in-house iPads, WiFi only, with Enterprise Developer, that I want to run a task on either, preferred in this order

A.) every hour
B.) every time they connect to a new wireless

Since I have Enterprise developer I don't need the app store approval.

I have read a few different ways of doing a background task but am trying to find the right method.

A.) Pretend to be a VoIP app. The app would start on startup and stay in the background but the user can close it. How do I force it to re-open?

B.) Play a empty sound file. Same issue as above and without the launch on startup?

C.) Significant location change. Don't know how to code it. Should run the task when they change wireless networks right? Even if it's not already open? Does it work without GPS and cellular? Ala http://preyproject.com/blog/2013/01/how-does-prey-work-on-iphone-ipad

Another app had issues with it though http://orbicule.blogspot.com/2012/12/discontinuing-undercover-ios.html

Ideas? Example code?

Comment: Not possible. iOS can and will terminate your app if it stays resident too long, no matter what voip/location hacks you try. You would have to jail break the devices to run a permanent service.

Answer (score 0):

The apps is in background?

This should be possible for in-house apps.

wi-fi change should be possible using the "Reachability" example from Apple, I guess. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

I would go for #C (significant location change). It can be acheived using the CLLocationManager framework

```
[[CLLocationManager sharedLocationManager] startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges]
```